# How do I check if the form is an add/edit/delete form?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I need to check if the form is for creating, editing, or deleting a node.

Currently, the below snippet allows me to check if the form is for adding or editing a node. How do I check if the form is for deleting a node?

```
    if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
      // The form is for creating a new node. 
    }
    else {
      // The form is for editing the node. 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use what said in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/211232), with a slight modification.

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos(request_path(), '/add') !== FALSE) {
    $page = 'add';
  }
  elseif (strpos(request_path(), '/edit') !== FALSE) {
    $page = 'edit';
  }
  else if (strpos(request_path(), '/delete') !== FALSE) {
    $page = 'edit';
  }
}
```

Comment: This one will not work when the form is embedded in pages other than those with the above URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form['#action'], '/add/') !== FALSE) {
      $page = 'add';
   }
  if (strpos($form['#action'], '/edit') !== FALSE) {
      $page = 'edit';
  }
  if (strpos($form['#action'], '/delete') !== FALSE) {
      $page = 'edit';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `$form_id` is `node_delete_confirm`

```php
if ($form_id == 'node_delete_confirm') {
  // delete form
}
else if (isset($node->is_new)) {
  // add form
}
else {
  // edit form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if (in_array($type, node_permissions_get_configured_types())) {
    if ($op == 'create') {
      //do somthing
    }

    if ($op == 'update') {
     //do somthing
    }
    if ($op == 'delete') {
    //do somthing
    }
  }
}
```

check this for more info 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x